# desktop launcher for ssh terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome, ssh, launcher

I have 3 ssh terminals defined for 3 headless systems on my lan.  I can launch them from a host terminal, but I would prefer to create a desktop file for each, so that I could put each one in the launcher menu (with an icon) and not need to go through the step of launching a terminal to launch another terminal.

So, stated simply: How can I create a gnome .desktop file that can launch an ssh session, and leave it open on the desktop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the following sample `.desktop` file, save the following contents as `somefile.desktop` at your desired location, say on desktop.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=system1_ssh_terminal
Comment=launch ssh session
Exec=gnome-terminal -e 'ssh -X user@ip_of_system1'
Icon=utilities-terminal
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Application;
```

Don't forget to make the `.desktop` file executable.

Comment: Thanks.  I missed the bit about .desktop files being executable.  Never found that in the gnome docs...